# Adding another HardDisk to my server

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hardware, hard-drive

I have a ubuntu server and I am planning to add another harddisk to it.

Currently installed harddisk is iSCSI drive and I can add new SATA2 harddisk using NAS or SAS.

I lack knowledge of linux in windows when a new harddisk is installed it is like a different partition on linux how would it work a partition or add up to current harddisk space automatically? wherein I can continue storing files in `/var/www/data`

Thank You.

Comment: I think you mean that your currently installed hard disk is SCSI, not iSCSI if it is physically inside of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, which includes Linux, partitions are physical space that you dedicate to a path. If you had only one partition, it would necessarily be allocated to '/', since this partition is mandatory.

If you wish to allocate physical space to `/var/www/data` using a specific partition, here is what you should do:

1. Create a new partition (on the same disk or another disk) and format it ;
2. Stop the services using the directory you wish to use as a mount point ;
3. Move the data in this directory to another place that has enough space ;
4. Find the identifier of your new partition ;
5. Mount the new partition on the path you wish to use ;
6. Put your data back in the directory.
7. Add the mount configuration in `/etc/fstab` to make sure your partition is mounted at startup.

Step 3 is important. If you don't do it, this is what will happen:

- Your data is stored on the original partition (let's say it's `/dev/sda1` for example) ;
- You mount the new partition on top of the directory (let's imagine this is `/dev/sdb2` for example) ;
- You see the directory being empty, because `/dev/sdb2` doesn't contain anything. The data are still stored in `/dev/sda1`, but you can't see them or remove them anymore, unless you unmount `/dev/sdb2` first.

This is why it's important to clean the directory before you mount a partition on it.

You can find more informations on using partitions on Linux on [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/).